# Expected value of a product of two random variables with sine

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables

I'm trying to compute the expected value of $$X_t = U \cdot \sin(Vt).$$ Here the vector $(U, V)$ has uniform distribution on the square $[0,1]^2$.

Here is what I've done so far:

The density of $(U, V)$ is $f_{UV}(x, y) = 1_{[0,1]^2}$.
We can write $\sin(Vt) = g(V)$ where $g(x) = \sin(xt)$, so $g^{-1}(y) = \frac{\arcsin(y)}{t}$ and we obtain the density of $\sin(Vt): \ f_{\sin(Vt)}(x) = \frac{1}{t \sqrt{1-x^2}} \cdot f_V(\frac{\arcsin(x)}{t})$.

We can find $f_V$ by integrating: $$\int_0^1 1 dx = 1$$

So $f_V(\frac{\arcsin(x)}{t})$ turns out to be the characteristic function of the set $\{ y : \ \arcsin (y) \in [0,t]\}$, but now there is a problem, because we don't know what $\sin(t)$ equals. Is it smaller or bigger than $1$?

I'm not sure if it's a good approach.

Could you tell me what I could do to find $\mathbb{E}X_t$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Law of the Unconscious Statistician,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) and find $\iint_S u\sin(vt)\,du\,dv$ on the square $S$.

Comment: So it seems that  the joint density is $1$. But how do we know that?

Comment: The vector $(U,V)$ has uniform distribution on the unit square. In this case, we could use single integrals because of independence. But I wanted to be a little more general.

Comment: And the joint density is the product of respective densities due to the independence. Thank you!

Comment: So we could write $\mathbb{E} (\varphi (U, V)) = \int \varphi (u, v) f_{U,V}(u,v) du dv = \int u \sin(vt) \cdot 1 du dv$ Is that correct?

Comment: Uniformly distributed on the square already means joint density $1$ on the square, $0$ elsewhere. If we wanted to find the expectation of $h(U,V)$, we would integrate $h(u,v)\cdto 1\,du\,dv$ over the square.

Comment: I see, that is what I needed to make sure about. Thanks a lot, again. Everything seems to be clear now.

Comment: To your last comment, yes, where in this case the (double) integral is taken over the square.

Comment: In your post, you tried to find the expectation of $\varphi(U,V)$ by first finding its distribution. This is doable in principle, but the Law of the Unconscious Statistician is ordinarily more efficient.